# expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to classes. I created a class called Counter which basically creates a counter object and has certain data members and function members associated with it.
The header file for the class is:

```
#ifndef c
#define c

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::vector; using std::string; using std::ostream;

class Counter{
  int v_;
  public:
    vector<string> log_;
    int initialized_;
    Counter(int);
    int value();
    int get_v() const { return v_; } //getter
    void set_v(int val) { v_ = val; } //setter
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, Counter &);
    friend Counter operator+(const Counter &, const Counter &);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &, Counter &);
Counter operator+(const Counter &, const Counter &);

#endif
```

and the cpp implementation file looks like this:

```
#include "counter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string; using std::vector; using std::ostream;

Counter::Counter(int a){
  v_ = a;
  initialized_ = a;
  log_.push_back("Constructor called with a " + std::to_string(a));
}

int Counter::value(){
  log_.push_back("value called. returned a " + std::to_string(v_));
  return (v_--);
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Counter & c){
  c.log_.push_back("<< called."); //line 1
  out << "Counter("<< c.initialized_ << ")@" << c.v_; //line 2
  return out;
}

Counter operator+(const Counter & c_one, const Counter & c_two){
  Counter c_three(c_one.initialized_ + c_two.initialized_);
  c_three.set_v(c_one.get_v()+c_two.get_v());
  return c_three;
}
```

When I compile the file I get bombarded with `expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token` in line 1 and line 2 of the "<<" operator overloaded function. I really have no idea as to why this is happening. Any help?

Comment: An include guard named `c` is a terrible idea. Use long, descriptive and *unlikely-to-conflict* names for your include guards. The preprocessor will not hesitate to clubber anything named `c` in your code so long as it encountered `#define c`.

Comment: Ah... and of course you have `Counter & c`. Could have guessed. That's your typo. It doesn't mix with the include guard.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica you are a beast. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `c`? You've defined it as nothing and then you use

```
c.log_.push_back(...)
```

Which the preprocessor changes to

```
.log_.push_back(...)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but the error clearly states it's looking for an expression before the period, where it appears you have none.